# jstl how to get each element json string

Tags: json, jstl

I have the following json string

```
[{"nombre":"Estadias Taller serieLoc. 251","array":[{"valores":

[{"nombre":"LUGO DE LLANERA","valor":1.89}],"ejeX":"IB1"},{"valores":[{"nombre":"LUGO DE LLANERA","valor":3.32}],"ejeX":"IB2"},{"valores":[{"nombre":"BARCELONA CAN TUNIS","valor":2.29},{"nombre":"LUGO DE LLANERA","valor":1.41},{"nombre":"TARRAGONA","valor":3.51}],"ejeX":"IS"}]},
{"nombre":"Estadias Taller serieLoc. 252 Merc","array":[{"valores":[{"nombre":"BARCELONA CAN TUNIS","valor":2.31}],"ejeX":"ES1"}]}]
```

This json string has two elements. The first is

```
 [{"nombre":"Estadias Taller serieLoc. 251","array":[{"valores":[{"nombre":"LUGO DE LLANERA","valor":1.89}],"ejeX":"IB1"},{"valores":[{"nombre":"LUGO DE LLANERA","valor":3.32}],"ejeX":"IB2"},{"valores":[{"nombre":"BARCELONA CAN TUNIS","valor":2.29},{"nombre":"LUGO DE LLANERA","valor":1.41},{"nombre":"TARRAGONA","valor":3.51}],"ejeX":"IS"}]}
```

The second one is

```
{"nombre":"Estadias Taller serieLoc. 252 Merc","array":[{"valores":[{"nombre":"BARCELONA CAN TUNIS","valor":2.31}],"ejeX":"ES1"}]}]
```

I want to get these two elements using jstl

I have the following for each

```
<c:forEach items="${vgraficas}" var="grafica"  >
        <p> grafica xxxx <c:out value="${grafica}" /></p>

</c:forEach>
```

But this loop gets every element in the string, not only two

```
grafica xxxx [{"nombre":"Estadias Taller serieLoc. 251"

grafica xxxx "array":[{"valores":[{"nombre":"LUGO DE LLANERA"

grafica xxxx "valor":1.89}]

grafica xxxx "ejeX":"IB1"}

grafica xxxx {"valores":[{"nombre":"LUGO DE LLANERA"

grafica xxxx "valor":3.32}]

grafica xxxx "ejeX":"IB2"}

grafica xxxx {"valores":[{"nombre":"BARCELONA CAN TUNIS"

grafica xxxx "valor":2.29}

grafica xxxx {"nombre":"LUGO DE LLANERA"

grafica xxxx "valor":1.41}

grafica xxxx {"nombre":"TARRAGONA"

grafica xxxx "valor":3.51}]

grafica xxxx "ejeX":"IS"}]}

grafica xxxx {"nombre":"Estadias Taller serieLoc. 252 Merc"

grafica xxxx "array":[{"valores":[{"nombre":"BARCELONA CAN TUNIS"

grafica xxxx "valor":2.31}]

grafica xxxx "ejeX":"ES1"}]}]
```

How can I get the two elements of this json array?

Comment: Where you are setting the attribute vgraficas's value ?

Comment: vgraficas's value is send from a java

Comment: What is the type of value... String or JSONArray ?

Answer (score -1):

Assuming vgraficas value's type in java is String.

1. Use the JavaScript function JSON.parse() to convert String into a JavaScript object. suppose it is obj.
2. Now this obj is basically array of objects. so the outer List will hold the array of Object (i.e. Object[]) which needs to be iterated again to fetch each object element one by one.

```
<c:forEach items="${obj}" var="outerVar"> 
      <c:forEach items="${outerVar}" var="innerVar"> // outerVar will hold your object array
         <c:out value="${innerVar}" /> // iterating the object array 
      </c:forEach>
  </c:forEach>
```